# Loop over list of lists and use ith iterator

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator, zip

So I have the following list of lists:

```
test = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I would like to loop over the `i`th element in the inner lists. I can do this by using `zip`:

```
for x, y, z in zip(test[0], test[1], test[2]):
    print(x, y, z)
```

Which returns:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Is there a cleaner, more Pythonic way to do this? Something like `zip(test, axis=0)`?

Comment: `for x, y, z in zip(*test):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use unpacking to pass the sublists of your input to `zip` as variable arguments:

```
for xyz in zip(*test):
    print(*xyz)
```

(and you can do the same for the x,y,z coords to pass params to `print`)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `numpy.array` you can simply use the `transpose` of the array and iterate over the rows

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> test = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> t = np.array(test)
>>> t
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Then to iterate

```
for row in t.T:
    print(row)

[1 4 7]
[2 5 8]
[3 6 9]
```

Depending what you intend to do, `numpy` will likely be more efficient than list comprehensions in general

Comment: The main question is more on getting the individual values into their respective variable than on printing. Thanks though!